# Laravel send data to multiple page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In laravel 7, I am getting data from db from a single route:

```
Route::get('/connection_view_details/{Cid}','ConnectionController@view_details');
```

I want to send the data to multiple page:

```
public function view_details($Cid)
{
    $Cid = base64_decode($Cid);
    
    
        $network_details = DB::table('connection_network_details')
                            ->where('Connection_id',$Cid)
                            ->first();
                            
     
    return view('connection.view_details',compact('network_details'));
    return view('connection.connection_detail_tables.network_details',compact('network_details'));
}
```

I want to retuen view of **view_details** page ,not the **network_details** page.but I want to send the variable **network_details** in the both pages.

Comment: **PHP return** statement immediately terminates the execution of a function when it is called from within that function.  So you cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function view_details($Cid)
{
    $Cid = base64_decode($Cid);
    
    
    $network_details = DB::table('connection_network_details')
                            ->where('Connection_id',$Cid)
                            ->first();
                            
    View::composer('connection.connection_detail_tables.network_details', function ($view) use ($network_details) {
        $view->with('network_details', $network_details);
    }); 
    return view('connection.view_details',compact('network_details'));
}
```

But you only can use that variable in that view only.